pagespeed reports "Serves images with low resolution" despite using picture tag
Pagespeed insights complains about my image size in the header when it tests my website with mobile. It states
"Image natural dimensions should be proportional to the display size and the pixel ratio to maximize image clarity."
My header image for desktop computers is sized at 131x130px and for mobile it's 66x65px. When pagespeed insights said I should change the smaller picture to the size 99x98px. so I did that and now its expecting the size 149x147px.
Since I work with pixels, I decided to work with the picture HTML tag instead of image srcset.
Here's my code:
In CSS:
@media(min-width:550px){
    #PIC{
        width:131px;
        height:130px;
    }
}

<picture>
    <source media="(min-width:550px)" srcset="/large.png">
    <img alt="logo" ID="PIC" src="/small.png" width=99 height=98>
</picture>

The only thing I could think of that might be a mistake is specifying the wrong pixel value for width, but then again, aren't most mobile smartphones less than 550 pixels wide?
I mean, a 66x65px image in a 550 pixel wide space couldn't be that low res could it?
also in my HTML header section, I have:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

Can anyone shed some light?
I also like the idea of the picture tag because any old-fashioned browser trying to view the page will be able to see the full sized image.
